# UI Automation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-ui-automation

Can anyone help me how to do UI Automation in WPF? I want to check the operation of a Grid.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to automate WPF and NOT WinForms, check out [Telerik's free framework](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/free-testing-framework.aspx). There's also a paid version if you want more features like record-and-playback.

Two open-source C# libraries that support automation of both WPF and WinForms controls are:

[White](http://white.codeplex.com/)

- I've used this, and found it to not always be reliable.

[QAliber](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qaliber/)

- I've used this, and found it to be good but needing work.

Both are open-source, so they'll show you how to use Microsoft's API's, and you can modify them to meet your needs.

I've also used Coded UI Test and Ranorex, but they're both $$, and I don't care for record-and-playback because I feel it's a maintenance issue. (Although QAliber does have a record-and-playback feature and White also has an alpha-quality recorder.)

Of course you could always go it directly from Microsoft's API's if you really want to get down and dirty.

Answer (score 1):

Use the tools built into Visual Studio - Coded UI Tests:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286681.aspx

There are two methods of doing this: Record and generate code (tends to be a good starting point, but often doesn't give you reproducible tests), and manually coding them up via UI object tree.

I ended up doing the second option most often, because I liked the code I wrote much better than what the recorder functionality offered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [PROJECT SIKULI](http://sikuli.org/):

> Sikuli is a visual technology to automate and test graphical user
>   interfaces (GUI) using images (screenshots). Sikuli includes Sikuli
>   Script, a visual scripting API for Jython, and Sikuli IDE, an
>   integrated development environment for writing visual scripts with
>   screenshots easily. Sikuli Script automates anything you see on the
>   screen without internal API's support. You can programmatically
>   control a web page, a Windows/Linux/Mac OS X desktop application, or
>   even an iphone or android application running in a simulator or via
>   VNC.

Comment: This doesn't have C# bindings as far as I've found.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham yes you are right, but you don't need it: "....Sikuli Script automates anything you see on the screen without internal API's support. You can programmatically control a web page, a Windows/Linux/Mac OS X desktop application..."

Comment: I've always been interested in trying this, but I never have. If it worked well though, it could be immensely valuable to have since it's entirely language agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good blog post to get you started on UI Automation:

[Silverlight UI Automation Testing using Prism 4.0](https://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/07/silverlight-ui-automation-testing-using.html)

It's Silverlight based, but the Silverlight is very close to WPF, and the UI Automation concepts involved are exactly the same.

Comment: link seems broken.

Comment: @MahbuburRahman - I've fixed it.